# Google map pointer onClick

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've 3 marker for different situations. I want to set click listener on all 3 markers (not on its title) to check which marker is showing. I implemented `OnMarkerClickListener` and `onMarkerClick` but no marker is getting clicked. Is there anything I'm missing? The code is a long one so just check the bottom for the `onMarkerClick` method.

```html
public class DriverMapFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>, OnMarkerClickListener{


 
 
 private Marker userStoreMarker, storeMarker_, storeMarker_test;
 
 
 
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.driver_map_page); 

  
  

  
  driver_arrived.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.nits.quick.cabapp_push");
    intent1.putExtra("message", "cancel");
    DriverMapFragmentActivity.this.sendBroadcast(intent1);
    driver_arrived.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    
   }
  });

  
  
  
 

 }




 
 
 


 public  void pssengerProfilePage(final HashMap<String, String> userdetailMap_) {
  try {


   if (userdetailMap_.get("from_user").equals("app")) {
    addressAdminTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    addressAdminTV.setText(userdetailMap_.get("address")); 
   }else{
    addressAdminTV.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    addressAdminTV.setText(userdetailMap_.get("address")); 
    driver_arrived.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
       //driverArrivedAlertMessage("You have arrived.",getString(R.string.app_name));
       
   }


   passengerDetailDialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PassDialogSlideAnim);
   // set title    
   passengerDetailDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);         
   passengerDetailDialog.setContentView(R.layout.passenger_profile_alert_page);
   passengerDetailDialog.setCancelable(false); 
   passengerDetailDialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
   passengerDetailDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); 

   
   
   CircleImageView pProfileImage = (CircleImageView)passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_notify_user_photo_imageView1);
   TextView pNameVText = (TextView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_user_name_textView1);          
   TextView pAddressdVText = (TextView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_address__textView2);
   TextView pPhoneVText = (TextView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_phone_no_textView3);
   ImageView pCallMobileVText = (ImageView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_call_mobile_imageView3);
   ImageView pSendSmsVText = (ImageView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_send_sms_imageView3);
   LinearLayout pSendSmsViewLL= (LinearLayout) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_send_sms_linearlayout);
   
   pCancelTripText = (ImageView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.p_cancel_trip_imageView3);

   if (userdetailMap_.get("from_user").equals("app")) {
    pCancelTripText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }else{
    pCancelTripText.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    pSendSmsViewLL.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }



   pNameVText.setText(userdetailMap_.get("pname"));
   final String fullName = userdetailMap_.get("pname");
   //pAddressdVText.setText(userdetailMap_.get("email"));
   pPhoneVText.setText(userdetailMap_.get("mobile"));
   //"tel:0377778888"
   final String phoneNumber = "tel:"+userdetailMap_.get("mobile");
   final String userId = userdetailMap_.get("id");
    Log.e("POSTsPageFragment adapter", "userdetailMap_:"+userdetailMap_);
   try {          

    String apiLink = userdetailMap_.get("image");
    // Log.d("Profile", "apiLink:"+apiLink);
    //String encodedurl = "";
    //encodedurl = apiLink.substring(0,apiLink.lastIndexOf('/'))+ "/"+ Uri.encode(apiLink.substring(
    //apiLink.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
    // Log.e("POSTsPageFragment adapter", "userdetailMap_:"+userdetailMap_);
    if ( apiLink != null  && !apiLink.equals("")) {
      Picasso.with(this) // Context : con
     .load(apiLink) // load: This path may be a remote URL, 
     .resize(100, 100)
     .placeholder(R.drawable.default_user)
     .error(R.drawable.default_user)
     .into(pProfileImage); // Into: ImageView into which the final image has to be passed
    }else{
     pProfileImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user);
    }
   } catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
   }
   pCallMobileVText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
     startActivity(callIntent);
    }
   });
   pSendSmsVText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //Log.d("DiverMapPage", "driver userId:"+userId);
     Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

     String name = userdetailMap.get("fname")+" "+userdetailMap.get("lname");
     bundle.putSerializable("userId", userdetailMap.get("id"));
     bundle.putSerializable("userName", name);
     bundle.putSerializable("opponentName", fullName);
     bundle.putSerializable("callFrom", "driver");
     bundle.putSerializable("opponentID", userId);
     // Open chat activity
     QuickCabChatActivity.start(DriverMapFragmentActivity.this, bundle);
    }
   });

   //Log.d("Profile", "userdetailMap_:"+userdetailMap_);

   pCancelTripText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     //Cancel trip
     String params = "action=cancelJobDriver&j_id="+userdetailMap_.get("jobid");
     DriverCancelTripTask driverCancelTrio = new DriverCancelTripTask();
     driverCancelTrio.execute(params);
     passengerDetailDialog.dismiss();
    }
   });
   // titleVText.setText(title);
   // TextView tvText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.mail_id_textView2);
   //tvText.setText(message);          

   ImageView closedialog = (ImageView) passengerDetailDialog.findViewById(R.id.profile_page_close_imageView1);
   closedialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){          
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // Do your stuff...                   
     passengerDetailDialog.dismiss();
    }
   });
   passengerDetailDialog.show(); 
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   e.printStackTrace();
  }        
 }


 
 


    


 
 

 @Override
 public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
  if (marker.equals(userStoreMarker)){
            System.out.println("userStoreMarker");
        }else if(marker.equals(storeMarker_)){
         System.out.println("storeMarker_");
        }else if(marker.equals(storeMarker_test)){
         System.out.println("storeMarker_test");
        }
  
  return true;
 }

 
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the marker click listener to the map doing:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); // mMap is your GoogleMap instance
```